# How to solve JSONDecodeError when using Poetry in Github Actions?

Tags: python, github-actions, python-poetry, python-3.10

#### Issue

I've got a problem using `poetry install` in my CI/CD pipeline (Github Actions), on any GitHub runner, since I migrated from Python 3.8 to Python 3.10.

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 79 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  • Installing pyparsing (3.0.9)
  
JSONDecodeError
  
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
  at /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.0/x64/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py:355 in raw_decode
      351│         """
      352│         try:
      353│             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
      354│         except StopIteration as err:
    → 355│             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
      356│         return obj, end
      357│ 
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I didn't change any lib configuration in my `pyproject.toml` file, but as you can see above: **Poetry hides most of the StackTrace.**

### What I tried

- Recreating the `poetry.lock` file.
- Removing the Poetry cache using `rm -r ~/.cache/pypoetry/cache/` (and `rm -r ~/.cache/pypoetry/`).
- Removing the lib that was returning an error (actually, the issue seems to happen with any lib, so that's the reason why I understand it's probably related to poetry and python)

### Question

**Any idea how to resolve this issue in my CI/CD pipeline?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a few researches, I found [this thread](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4210) on the poetry GitHub repository from november 2021.

There is this workaround from [hoefling GitHub user](https://github.com/hoefling):

> **Disabling poetry's experimental new installer may be a workaround for
> now:**

#### Solution

```bash
poetry config experimental.new-installer false
```

**Adding this line in the shell before running the `poetry install` command resolved my problem!**

---

---

Note that in the same thread, another comment from [ddc67cd](https://github.com/ddc67cd) stated that:

> the issue is resolved with the new version of **cachecontrol==0.12.9** (it should be installed automatically).

But running `pip install -U cachecontrol` didn't resolve the issue in my specific case (might be worth testing otherwise?).

---

---

*It also seems the problem came back recently (July 2022) and [this comment](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4210#issuecomment-1178776203) suggested a possible root cause to the issue related to the setuptools library.*

Anyway, disabling poetry's experimental new installer should resolve the problem for now, until a permanent solution is found.